# How makes dragging operations on rows without disrupt table layout in java?

Tags: java, swing, layout, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I have a method for dragging.

```
public void switchRows(int dropped, int dragged) {

    if (dragged == dropped) {
        return;
    }

    keys.add(dropped, keys.get(dragged));
    keys.remove(dragged < dropped ? dragged : dragged + 1);
}
```

And I invoke that method here ==>

```
protected void importString(JComponent c, String str) {
    target = (JTable) c;

    int dropped = target.getDropLocation().getRow();

    Integer dragged = Integer.valueOf(str);

    Class1 temp = workspace.getSourceMap().get(filter.getSelectedItem()).set(dropped, workspace.getSourceMap().
            get(filter.getSelectedItem()).get(dragged));
    workspace.getSourceMap().get(filter.getSelectedItem()).set(dragged, temp);

    MyTable.switchRows(dropped, dragged);
}
```

But it disrupts table layout. All rows getting mixed. When user drag a row with mouse to another place I wanna protect table layout and only changes thats row's place ; not all rows in table. 
Thanks.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: It's a big project. It's too hard to share all related code. As you see , is there any wrong on the structure of this code. Thanks bro.

Comment: It's hard to know, `MyTable.switchRows(dropped, dragged);` this could be stuffing things up, or your `workspace` could be stuffing things up. The fact that those two are separated is of concern, as the table should be responding to changes to the model